# Как конвертировать файлы .java в файлы .kt?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, конвертация, kotlin

Прочитал тут [habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/231525](http://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/231525) статью. Там написано, что просто конвертируется. Но в IDEA не нашёл меню, отвечающего за конвертацию. Как осуществить это?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить действие "Convert Java File to Kotlin File". Это можно сделать несколькими способами:

1. Выполняем действие "Find Action" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> и набираем имя действия.
2. Также эта опция доступна в меню "Code | Convert Java File to Kotlin File".

Естественно у вас должен быть установлен [плагин Kotlin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=androidstudio), либо используйте Intellij IDEA 15, в которой этот плагин предоставляется ["из коробки"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть подробный урок о переходе на Kotlin: http://java-help.ru/kotlin-introduction/

Comment: Уже побывал там. Для начала подойдёт.