# Переписываем проект

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Если я хочу частино/постепенно вносить изменения в класс .java своими дополнениями/изменениями Kotlin.

Во-первых, возможно ли это? Не хочется сразу переводить класс посредством [hotkey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475499/211117).

Во-вторых, как правильней будет это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете вносить изменения в java класс посредством внедрения в него kotlin кода, т.к. kotlin создает свой класс с расширением kt. Вы можете писать либо полностью класс на kotlin либо писать расширения для java классов на kotlin

Comment: можно пожалуйста чуточку поподробней про ''писать расширения для java классов на kotlin''?

Comment: В котлине есть такое понятие как Extensions. Это дает возможность расширять класс без наследования https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html